# Call swift method from Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, syntax

Sounds dumb but...

I've a swift class with a public method

```
class PlayerVC: UIViewController {
  func retrievePixelBufferToDraw(strongSelf: PlayerVC) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    ...
    return pixelBuffer
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call it from an Objective-C class (disclaimer I'm a beginner with Objective-C and I could find the answer online..) like:

```
PlayerVC* VC = self.playerController;
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [VC retrievePixelBufferToDraw:VC];
```

But the syntax is not correct. (`No visible @interface for 'PlayerVC' declares the selector 'retrievePixelBufferToDraw:'`) I've tried a variety of bracketing, colons, variable names etc

Comment: #import "<PROJECT_NAME>-Swift.h" then method name will be 'retrievePixelBufferToDrawWithStrongSelf' ... Check "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name" field in your build settings

Comment: thanks, I figured it out thanks to the autocomplete. Do you know why the method name and parameter name get merged in `retrievePixelBufferToDrawWithStrongSelf` ?

Comment: auto generated ObjC header will make method names like that. Same goes to other way. eg. if your ObjC class have method let say "initWithName:" swift will see it (when you properly bridge) as func init(name:)

Comment: Not sure why question downvoted, it helps me a lot to figure out the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the answer is:

```
PlayerVC* VC = self.playerController;
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [VC retrievePixelBufferToDrawWithStrongSelf:VC];
```

No idea where the `retrievePixelBufferToDrawWithStrongSelf` is coming from, maybe from the auto bridging between Swift and Objective C. That sounds awful. Anyway..!

Comment: It's coming from `retrievePixelBufferToDraw(strongSelf: PlayerVC)`